# using .o files in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I've just learn something about makefile and here is my first question for it.I have main.cpp hello.cpp factorial.cpp and functions.h files

```
all: hello

hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *o hello
```

In the code above, why files have an extention .o ? shouldnt be .cpp or what is the differences between using .cpp and .o

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building a C++ program is a two-stage process. First, you **compile** each `.cpp` file into a `.o` object file. Compiling converts the source code into machine code but doesn't resolve function calls from other source files (since they haven't been compiled yet).

```
main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

factorial.o: factorial.cpp
    g++ -c factorial.cpp

hello.o: hello.cpp
    g++ -c hello.cpp
```

Second, you **link** the object files together to create an executable. Linking resolves the external references in each object file.

```
hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
    g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello
```

By the way, there is a typo in the `clean` target. `*o` should be `*.o`.

```
clean:
    rm -rf *.o hello
```

Comment: one more question. How It avoids unnecesarry compiling? I mean makefile is used to decrease compile time .Isnt it? now here,hello says that go to main.o factorial.o and hello.o and all of them compiles main.cpp factorial.cpp and hello.cpp respectively.Finally all these 3 object files are compiled again.So all files are compiled even if we use makefile ?

Comment: @Eday Make won't rebuild targets if it doesn't have to. If factorial.o exists, and factorial.cpp hasn't changed, it won't rebuild factorial.o. Similarly if `hello` was already built and none of the `.o` files has changed it won't rebuild `hello`.

Comment: I'm so greathful for your helps.Thanks again! The last thing I want to ask is that I saw 2 lines in a makefile and these are $(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS) 
 $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@  and 
.cpp.o:
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ what kind of these are ? is it bash ? and how should I learn purpose of these lines ?

Answer (score 2):

`.o` denote "object-files", these are files compiled from source but not yet linked into an executable or a library.
In your make-file, i.e.

```
main.o : main.cpp
```

says that `main.o` will be created from `main.cpp` using `g++ -c main.cpp`.

Eventually, all files with `.o` will create the executable `hello` as stated in

```
hello: main.o factorial.o hello.o
     g++ main.o factorial.o hello.o -o hello
```

Comment: what differs if I only changes .o with .cpp ??

Comment: `.o`-files are binaries, opening them with a text-editor you would get rather random symbols, there is nothing left of your initial source-code.

Comment: @Eday the advantage of first compiling each .cpp file into an object file (.o) is that if you make changes to one of your .cpp files, you only need to re-compile the according .o file and re-link all .o files into an executable. If you would do something like `g++ -o hello *.cpp`, you always would have to re-compile _all_ files, even if most of them are unchanged.

Comment: @ThomasKühn thanks for info.One more question what is the purpose of the part after colon ? Does the right side of colon specify whether the target is compiled or not ?